# Unable to download file having special characters in name

Tags: asp.net

I have some code which looks like following:
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path);
Here "path" is complete path of the document. This is working fine in all browser for special characters like é , but fail in IE except IE9.Issue is like somthing this this link http://blogs.adamsoftware.net/Web_Development/Thecaseofthestrangefilenames.aspx       !